# Using PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true with connection string

Tags: php, pdo

Does anybody know how to use `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true` using the constructor?

```
$handle = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$myServer;Database=$myDB");
```

Comment: did you try PDO::__constructor manual page?

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to use persistent connections, you must set PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT in the array of driver options passed to the PDO constructor for ex...

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass, array(
PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
));
?>
```

**If you're using the PDO ODBC driver and your ODBC libraries support ODBC Connection Pooling (unixODBC and Windows are two that do; there may be more), then it's recommended that you don't use persistent PDO connections, and instead leave the connection caching to the ODBC Connection Pooling layer.**